# The tough one from "A Brilliant Young Mind" (2014)

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, combinatorics

Great movie by the way. I'm quoting from memory, so I may get the wording wrong.

> The positive integers are each colored Red, Yellow or Green.
>   Prove that for any such coloring, there must exist three distinct positive integers $a,b,c$ such that the colors of $~a$, $~b$, $~c$, $~a+b$, $~a+c$, $~b+c$, and $~a+b+c~$ are all the same.

The integers must be non-zero, but they do not have to be distinct.

Comment: I want to note I've found a solution for two colours, and set {a,b} where a,b,a+b are the same colour. I made a tree of possible colourings and solved it 5 deep. But I'm not sure if this can be done with the full problem. 

Based on the movie, the solution may require a reduction to a different but equal problem.

Comment: Is there any order to how they are colored: 1=red, 2=yellow, 3=green, 4=red, 5=yellow... or should we assume the potential for random distribution?

Comment: @tfitzger you have to show one exists for ANY ordering

Comment: @kaine is that even possible, though? I mean, if it is truly a random distribution, the color has no relation to the ordinal position of the number, which means there is no relation between `a`, `b`, and `a+b` in terms of color.

Comment: @tfitzger, hence why it is a puzzle.  It seems possible it might work but it is not easy.  Can you show there is a configuration that doesn't work?

Comment: Reminds me of [Coloring the reals](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17962/colouring-the-reals)

Comment: I can get everything except for $a+c$ to be the same color... this is tricky.

Comment: @Lopsy, If that's true I can prove that that occurs infinitely many times. Does that help? ;p

Comment: Does this [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem) help?

Comment: @SeraphCheng That theorem looks like an immediate solution for the degenerate case $a=b=c$, where the 7 possibilities reduces to just $a, 2a, 3a$.

Answer (score 10):

The question concerns a special case of "Hindman's theorem":

> **Hindman's theorem**
>   Suppose that the natural numbers are colored with $r$ different colors. 
>   Then there exists a color $c$ and an infinite set $D$ of natural numbers, so that all elements of $D$ are colored with $c$ and so that every finite sum of elements of $D$ also has color $c$.

For solving the puzzle, you just apply Hindman's theorem with $r=3$ colors (red, yellow, green). The theorem gives you an infinite mono-chromatic set $D$, from which you may pick three arbitrary elements $a,b,c$; these three elements have all desired properties.

Additional information:

- A [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_set) article on so-called IP sets and Hindman's theorem
- The article *"A Simple Proof and Some Difficult Examples for Hindman's Theorem"* by Henry Towsner on the [arXive](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3885)
- Example 3 in the [Tricki](http://www.tricki.org/article/How_to_use_ultrafilters) article *"How to use ultrafilters"* contains another proof of Hindman's theorem

Comment: Suggested reading: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.3885v3.pdf .  This might have fit better on Math.SE

Comment: @kaine: I have added your reference to the text. (Hope that's okay with you.)

Comment: Any chance the general proof has a more accessible explanation when limited to 3 colors?

Comment: @xnor The Tricki article on ultrafilters is more accessible than the arxiv post (at least for me), but it still requires mathematical maturity. http://www.tricki.org/article/How_to_use_ultrafilters Background: an ultrafilter is a way of calling some subsets of natural numbers "large" and other subsets "small." Every subset must be either large or small, and given a subset S, exactly one of S or its complement is large.

Comment: @Lopsy: I have added your reference to the text;