Prove that no matter how the points are colored that there is an isosceles triangle inscribed in the circle whose vertices are all the same color
Some points of a circle are colored red; the rest are colored blue. Prove that no matter how the points are colored that there is an isosceles triangle inscribed in the circle whose vertices are all the same color.

Attribution:  I. Tonov

A problem whose solution also proves this: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17962/colouring-the-reals/17966#17966

Consider the following set of points:

 5 points, evenly spaced so that they form the vertices of a regular pentagon.

If you choose any three of these points, they form an isosceles triangle,

 with two equal edges and a diagonal, or two equal diagonals and an edge.
 Whichever colour is the in the majority amongst those 5 points can provide at least 3 points of the same colour, which will form an isosceles triangle.

