Prove no matter how the points are colored, that within the line there exists a line segment with its endpoints and midpoint colored the same
Every point of a straight line is colored either red or blue.
Prove no matter how the points are colored, that within the line there exists a line segment of non-zero length with its endpoints and midpoint colored the same.
Assume standard 2-dimensional Euclidean Geometry.

Attribution:  Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience)

I think this is the same as this puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17962/4551 It asks to color all the reals but the solutions there also work for an interval.

@xnor I also feel they are the same.

2-dimensional? That seems like a lot of dimensions for a single straight line.

@Bass I was envisioning the line to be in 2-dimensional space which was the type of space that I learned about when I first took a Geometry course.

@xnor I don’t like posting duplicate questions.  I failed here.  How did you discover the duplicate question?

@Will.Octagon.Gibson I remembered it because I had answered it :) But yeah, it seems really hard to search for that one, especially since it doesn't use terms like "midpoint"

I played around with different configurations using MS Excel, trying to find a red/blue pattern that would create a line that satisfied the conditions, and eventually realized that I couldn't link many points at all without a contradiction..
The longest line I could find that satisfied the conditions was 8 points long:

 

 and its inverse
 


When we try to add to either side we are forced into creating a line that does not satisfy the conditions. The M marks the matching points:

 

Therefore, any segment of 9 or more points is guaranteed to show that there cannot exist a line segment that has its endpoints and midpoint all the same color.


  As the diagram shows below, we label all the red points using $R_1, R_{2}, ..., R_{n}$. And the number of blue points between every two neighboring red points is $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1}$.  
 

 Now we start by assuming that the midpoints of all red points are not red, then we can derive that $x_{1} \ne x_{2} \ne ... \ne x_{n-1}$.  
 Case 1: If there are more than 5 red points (or equal to 5) in this straight line, then there must be at least one $x_{i}$ that satisfy $x_{i} \geq 3$, i.e. at least one segment is consisted of 3 (or more) consecutive blue points.  
 Case 2: If there are 4 red points in this straight line. To avoid the $x_{i} \geq 3$, the only possible arrangement should be like this: (the 1st, 3rd, 4th red points satisfy the rule)


